# Removing the Ubuntu 16.04 Operating System

Tags: delete

Can the Ubuntu 16.04 Operating System be removed / emptied from my computer? Help me to solve this, I want to restore my computer like a new situation, which is without an operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need boot using for example Ubuntu Live CD or Live USB and format your device where Ubuntu OS is installed.

For example you have one HDD\SSD where current Ubuntu OS installed. When you completely boot from Live CD/USB, goto Applications -> type in search field "**disks**" and run **Disks** app. Then select your HDD\SSD and push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  to format Partition. Turn Erase switch to **ON**, select Type of new File System and click <kbd>Next</kbd> button (right top corner of current window).

Another way you can run Applications -> **GParted** and do same with another interface: https://gparted.org/livecd.php

Answer (score 1):

Simply formatting your computer leaves your data accessible to a clever hacker.

Better to zero out your hard drive so that no data can be recovered.

This can be done using dd when booted from a USB flash drive running Ubuntu Live.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx
```

where sdx is the hard drive partition. (ie sda)

This method can take time.

Comment: Isn’t formatting with the Erase option enabled (see [S_Flash’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1092470/250300)) comparable with manually filling zeroes?

Comment: @Melebius: Some people prefer command line, both get the job done. dd works even if you can only boot to command line.